# Mermaid diagrams not rendering correctly in Rmarkdown xaringan presentations

Tags: r, r-markdown, diagrammer, xaringan, mermaid

I am attempting to make some simple flowcharts in an Rmarkdown html presentation I am rendering with xaringan. I'm drawing mermaid diagrams using the `DiagrammeR` package. However, although the charts display correctly in the Rstudio viewer the styling does not appear in the presentation output.

For instance

```
DiagrammeR::mermaid("
graph LR;
A((Orange)) --> B((Grey));

classDef orange fill:#f96;
classDef grey fill:#d3d3d3;
class A orange;
class B grey;
")
```

generates one orange node and one grey node as expected when run at the console. However,

````
---
title: "Simple Example" 
output: 
  xaringan::moon_reader
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)
```

## Flow chart

```{r example, fig.align='center', fig.retina=3}
DiagrammeR::mermaid("
graph LR;
A((Orange)) --> B((Grey));

classDef orange fill:#f96;
classDef grey fill:#d3d3d3;
class A orange;
class B grey;
")
```
````

generates the flowchart in the default mermaid colors ignoring the styling.

Does anyone know a workaround for this? I would also be open to suggestions of other packages for drawing simple tree diagrams.

Answer (score 2):

The mermaid creates a htmlwidget as output. You should wrap it into a `<iframe>` section. The [widgetframe](https://github.com/bhaskarvk/widgetframe) package can do this for you, other htmlwidget-based apps like DT, leaflet, Dygraph can be embeded into xaringan with this method.

````
---
title: "Simple Example" 
output: 
  xaringan::moon_reader
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)
```

## Flow chart

```{r example, fig.align='center', fig.retina=3}

suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(widgetframe))


l=DiagrammeR::mermaid("
graph LR;
A((Orange)) --> B((Grey));

classDef orange fill:#f96;
classDef grey fill:#d3d3d3;
class A orange;
class B grey;
")

widgetframe::frameWidget(l)
```
````

Comment: Thanks this is a great answer, but suffers the limitation that it gives the diagram a white background which looks unfortunately with non-white slides. Weirdly I found that if you style the nodes individually `style A fill:#d3d3d3` it works fine.

Comment: They are plain html/CSS/js, I'm suspecting the reason why codes don't work in your question is that that the CSS/js of xaringan is interfering with the mermaid CSS/js. but that's pretty difficult to debug I'm afraid.

Comment: @gfgm I just found out that if you use widgetframe::frameableWidget(l) instead of widgetframe::frameWidget(l), it keeps the default transparent background.