# Mermaid (diagrammeR) graph not displayed in RPres

Tags: r, diagrammer, rpres

I am trying to include a graph built with the `diagrammeR` package in an `RPres`. That's the graph:

```
library(DiagrammeR)
mermaid("graph TD
          X1(X1)-->Z1(Z2)
          X2(X2)-->Z2(Z2)
          X1(X1)-->Z2(Z2)
          Z1(Z1)-->Y(Y)
          Z2(Z2)-->Y(Y)
            ")
```

Looking at the output in RStudio's viewer pane is no problem. No I include it in an RPres:

````
Untitled
========================================================
author: 
date: 
autosize: true

First Slide
========================================================

```{r,echo=FALSE, results = "asis"}

library(DiagrammeR)
mermaid("graph TD
          X1(X1)-->Z1(Z2)
          X2(X2)-->Z2(Z2)
          X1(X1)-->Z2(Z2)
          Z1(Z1)-->Y(Y)
          Z2(Z2)-->Y(Y)
            ")
````

(note that the "```" to close the code chunk aren't displayed here because of markup...)

Alas, nothing but the abyss of emptiness:

[image]

Comment: The mermaid creates a htmlwidget as output. Perhaps you could wrap it into a <iframe> section. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58689080/mermaid-diagrams-not-rendering-correctly-in-rmarkdown-xaringan-presentations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you committed to `RPres` or would you consider alternative slide formats? For example,  if you create a new R Markdown document and specify `output: ioslides_presentation` in the YAML header, the diagram will render properly:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Your Name"
date: "5/2/2020"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

Untitled
===========================================================
Here is the content for the second slide in different style


## Title of Mermaid Slide

```{r,echo=FALSE, results = "asis"}

library(DiagrammeR)
mermaid("graph TD
          X1(X1)-->Z1(Z2)
          X2(X2)-->Z2(Z2)
          X1(X1)-->Z2(Z2)
          Z1(Z1)-->Y(Y)
          Z2(Z2)-->Y(Y)
        ")
````

Which produces this:

[image]